# Fade in out animation Angular +2

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to fade the new element in, and fade it out when I deleted it.

```
animations: [
        trigger('enterAnimation', [
            transition(':enter', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(800, style({opacity: 1}))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                state('invisible', style({opacity: 0})),
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(800, style({opacity: 0}))
            ])
        ])
    ],
```

And this is my template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" [@enterAnimation]='item.state'>
...
...
```

Now the fade in is work fine, but when I delete the item, I'm changing the item from visible to invisible but the element doesn't disappeared.

Comment: just `<div *ngFor="let item of data" @enterAnimation>`. Let me know if it works

Comment: remove the state both from template and animation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsdfuv-xopq1p

Answer (score 4):

1. States should be outside the transition. If they're inside, they're only applied during the transition.
2. Since you use a loop, you should use a custom trackBy function to be sure that your items are correctly added/removed.
3. Because you rely on entering and leaving transitions, you don't need to give a parameter to your animation attribute.

This leaves you with this

```
trigger('Fading', [
  state('void', style({ opacity: 0 })),
  state('*', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  transition(':enter', animate('800ms ease-out')),
  transition(':leave', animate('800ms ease-in')),
]);
```

And in your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" @Fading>
```

Note that your items will only fade, they won't collapse or anything. So don't be shocked if yo usee erratic behavior, that's because you made a very simple animation.